# Python HVPLOT In a future version of pandas a length 1 tuple will be returned when iterating over a groupby with a grouper equal to a list of length 1

Tags: python, pandas, hvplot

I am working on a data visualization using Python's Pandas, hvplot, and Panel libraries.

I am able to shape the dataframe as I want, but when it comes to plotting this in hvplot. I start getting the following errors:

```
/home/****/_git/data-science-books/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/holoviews/core/data/pandas.py:231: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas, a length 1 tuple will be returned when iterating over a groupby with a grouper equal to a list of length 1. Don't supply a list with a single grouper to avoid this warning.
  data = [(k, group_type(v, **group_kwargs)) for k, v in
```

If I supply multiple params to the 'by' param in hvplot, I don't get errors, but the chart is broken.

Any thoughts?

The preprocessing steps clean a series of books in .txt files into a pandas dataframe that looks like the following: (each word in the book is stored in the 'words' column)

|  | words | book_title | publish_date | author | genre | country_of_origin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | riders | Riders of the Purple Sage | 1912 | Zane Grey | western | united states |
| 1 | by | Riders of the Purple Sage | 1912 | Zane Grey | western | united states |
| 2 | contents | Riders of the Purple Sage | 1912 | Zane Grey | western | united states |
| 26 | illustrations | Riders of the Purple Sage | 1912 | Zane Grey | western | united states |
| 39 | chapter | Riders of the Purple Sage | 1912 | Zane Grey | western | united states |

Then we make the DF interactive for hvplot and panel.

`imaster = master.interactive()`

Create a pipeline for hvplotting.

```
colors = ['white', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet', 'purple']

pipeline = (
    imaster[
        (imaster.publish_date >= year_range_slider.value[0]) &
        (imaster.publish_date <= year_range_slider.value[1]) &
        (imaster.words.isin(colors))
         ]
    .drop(['country_of_origin', 'book_title', 'author'], axis=1)
    .rename(columns={"genre":"word_count"})
    .groupby(['publish_date','words']).count()
)
```

RESULTING INTERACTIVE PLOT

```
                word_count
publish_date    words   
-700            blue    8
                green   8
                purple  13
                red 11
                violet  1
                white   27
                yellow  6
1908            blue    12
                green   9
                orange  2
                purple  1
                red 10
                violet  1
                white   13
                yellow  7
1912            blue    31
                green   28
                purple  62
                red 72
                violet  2
                white   114
                yellow  2
```

It's when I attempt to plot this that I start to see issues. It appears that I get 2 identical errors each time I call hvplot. The first pair on the line plot, the second pair on the scatter plot, and the third pair when I combine them into 'color_plot'

```
color_plot_line = pipeline.hvplot.line(x ='publish_date', by='words', y='word_count', title='Colors by Year')
color_plot_scatter = pipeline.hvplot.scatter(x ='publish_date', by='words', y='word_count', title='Colors by Year')
color_plot = color_plot_line * color_plot_scatter
color_plot
```

```
/home/***/_git/data-science-books/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/holoviews/core/data/pandas.py:231: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas, a length 1 tuple will be returned when iterating over a groupby with a grouper equal to a list of length 1. Don't supply a list with a single grouper to avoid this warning.
  data = [(k, group_type(v, **group_kwargs)) for k, v in
/home/***/_git/data-science-books/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/holoviews/core/data/pandas.py:231: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas, a length 1 tuple will be returned when iterating over a groupby with a grouper equal to a list of length 1. Don't supply a list with a single grouper to avoid this warning.
  data = [(k, group_type(v, **group_kwargs)) for k, v in
/home/***/_git/data-science-books/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/holoviews/core/data/pandas.py:231: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas, a length 1 tuple will be returned when iterating over a groupby with a grouper equal to a list of length 1. Don't supply a list with a single grouper to avoid this warning.
  data = [(k, group_type(v, **group_kwargs)) for k, v in
/home/***/_git/data-science-books/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/holoviews/core/data/pandas.py:231: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas, a length 1 tuple will be returned when iterating over a groupby with a grouper equal to a list of length 1. Don't supply a list with a single grouper to avoid this warning.
  data = [(k, group_type(v, **group_kwargs)) for k, v in
/home/***/_git/data-science-books/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/holoviews/core/data/pandas.py:231: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas, a length 1 tuple will be returned when iterating over a groupby with a grouper equal to a list of length 1. Don't supply a list with a single grouper to avoid this warning.
  data = [(k, group_type(v, **group_kwargs)) for k, v in
/home/***/_git/data-science-books/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/holoviews/core/data/pandas.py:231: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas, a length 1 tuple will be returned when iterating over a groupby with a grouper equal to a list of length 1. Don't supply a list with a single grouper to avoid this warning.
  data = [(k, group_type(v, **group_kwargs)) for k, v in
```

I have tried to adjust the 'by' param to include a list longer than 1. This stops the error, but does not produce the plot as expected.

`color_plot_line = pipeline.hvplot.line(x ='publish_date', by=['words', 'word_count'], y='word_count', title='Colors by Year')`

Sending a single value into 'by' produces the plot, but also the errors.

Current plot (not well hydrated data):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

---

I experienced the exact same warning in my own data analytics code using the same modules (all modules up to date).

However my charts where never broken and always come out as expected (except see legend image below) when supplying a list of length 1 or more based on a param to hvplot using "by".

---

This code would produce the same warning using a param ListSelector widget when only 1 element was selected i.e. on startup.

```
events = param.ListSelector(default=["F01-01"], objects=["F01-01","F01-02"], label="Event Selector")
...
#On startup df has only 1 event in the Events column
df.hvplot(
    x="Time (s)",
    y="height",
    by="Events"
)
```

In the end I went with a loop and a simple filter

```
plots = []
for event in self.events:
    df = df[df["Event"] == event]
    plots.append(
         df.hvplot(
             x="Time (s)",
             y="height",
             label="height",
         )
    )
hv.Overlay(plots)
.opts(width=1800, height=1000, legend_position="right")
.relabel(", ".join(self.events))
```

Weird error in the legend when using "by"

[Weird error in the legend using hvplot and "by"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsKID.png)